# How does getopt(3) work, and what is the 'extern' variable optarg?

Tags: c, unix, getopt

I am trying to learn how to accept command line arguments and accompanying data following flags, i.e.

```
myprogram -sampleflag datahere
```

My code is here so far. *getopt()* throws data into a variable *c*, and apparently you can access *optarg* from outside the function it was called. How is this possible? According to the man page, my code should work! However, as you can see the output is (null).

#### my code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    opterr = 0;
    char* cvalue = NULL;
    int c;
    char* optarg = hello;

while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "ps")) != -1){
    switch(c){
        case 'p':
            cvalue = optarg;
            printf("cvalue is : %s\n", cvalue );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

#### my output: ($ myprogram -p test)

```
cvalue is : (null)
```

Comment: +1 Congratulations on asking well formatted question.

Comment: Thanks! First one too!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If it's the first of more-to-come questions I encourage you to use a "real" user name. I tend to ignore userNNNNNNN questions because of the general low quality and "do my work for me" things that are asked.

Comment: @StephenP I have the opposite experience; personally I never rate a question based on the handle.

Comment: @self — I don't *rate* based on the handle, but I'm less likely to spend my time on "drive-by" questions — there are so many bad ones from anonymous users who can't be bothered to search before asking and I'm sick of wasting what little "free" time I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt):

> An option character in this string can be followed by a colon (‘:’) to indicate that it takes a required argument.

So in your case your string for options should be `"p:s"` rather than `"ps"`.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I had just figured it out right after you had commented!